# Get object dynamically with the name stored in a variable

Tags: symfony, attributes, twig

Here is my problem :

I know how to get an attribute dynamically with the function attribute(), but it still needs to provide the "root" object sent in the twig template.

I need to get this root object but i don't have his name directly, its name is stored in twig variable above. Here is the context :

```
{% set entityName = "country" %}

... some codes ...

{% set route_form = 'admin_'~entityName~'_update' %}
{% set url_form = path(route_form, {entityName.id} ) %}
```

i know i receive in the template an object with name `country` so i need to get `country.id` to generate the url.

How can i get the object `country` with the name stored in a variable ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you pass a country object to the template you should have access to country.id. If you don't have access to country.id, you haven't passed the country object correctly to the twig template. What does your controller look like?

Comment: I have access to country directly, i know. But this is not my question. I need to get the object by his name stored in a variable. Because i'm working on a generator, i won't not know the name of the object passed in the template, only an above variable will have the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You can use `_context`*

**Doc** : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#global-variables

```
{% set entityName = "country" %}

{% set route_form = 'admin_'~entityName~'_update' %}

{% set url_form = path(route_form, {  _context[entityName].id     } ) %}
```

Comment: wow, nice, thanks man :) i didn't know this 3 globals variables, very helpful.